# How to include derived images from database into css file

Tags: php, css

I would like to derive my website background image from database.those background images are loading through `banner.css` file.

```
banner.css 

<?
header("Content-type: text/css");  
include("getfrontimage.php");
$theme = "images";
$size = "cover";
$height = "780px";

?>
<style>
.w3layouts-banner-top{
    background: url(<?php  echo $theme.'/'.$row1[image];?>) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -webkit-background-size: <?php echo  $size; ?>;
    -moz-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -o-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;     
    -moz-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    min-height: <?php echo $height; ?>;
}
.w3layouts-banner-top1{ 
    background: url(<?php echo  $theme.'/'.$row2[image]; ?>) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -webkit-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -moz-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -o-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;     
    -moz-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    min-height: <?php echo   $height; ?>;
}
.w3layouts-banner-top2{
    background: url(<?php echo $theme.'/'.$row3[image]; ?>) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -webkit-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -moz-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;
    -o-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;     
    -moz-background-size: <?php echo $size; ?>;   
    min-height: <?php echo $height; ?>;
}
</style>
```

But background images are not loading in my website.
I refer this links
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504928/make-php-code-into-css-file)

please give me any idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: I would assume you can only do it inside the markup, as php code run there, but not in the css files.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I didn't get sir

Comment: Where's your code to initialise variables like $row1, $row2 etc? You may inspect the CSS file from your browser to see if all those variables are set properly.

Comment: You might need to rename your file to `.php` unless otherwise you have set your server to parse the php code in `.css` file.

Comment: @art06 i initialize into include("getfrontimage.php"); file.. and i tried that also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row1[image]` must be `$row1['image']`, because the array key can either be an integer or a string. If you enable [display of warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/7663972), you'll get a message in this case: 
`Warning: Use of undefined constant image` Correct the other variables.

Processing PHP code in files with the .css extension is not a not quite optimal solution, because you need to add special directives so that your web server processes css files as php files. It is easier to include CSS rules in a php file, and then add the css file to a web page using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.php">
```

By the way, [short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185336/7663972) `<?= $size ?>` are more readable than `<?php echo $size; ?>`.

Comment: Did my answer help to solve the problem, @Arebhy Sri?